# Imaginary Number Adding One Explanation

Tags: complex-numbers

On Khan Academy there is this question.

$$0.33i−i^3$$

I don't understand how the answer is:

$$0+1.33i$$

Could someone please explain why it's adding $1$ to the $0.33$?

Comment: What is $i^3$? Can you calculate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$i^2=-1 \Rightarrow i^3=-i \Rightarrow-i^3=i$

so $0.33i + i = i(1+0.33)=1.33i$

Comment: I think you meant to put a period, not a comma.

Comment: oh, you are right, but in italy it doesn't make a huge difference, so sometimes i forgot to check^^

Answer (score 2):

$$0.33i−i^3=(0.33-i^2)i=(0.33-(-1))i=(0.33+1)i=1.33i+0$$

"Q.E.D."